# Program Movesense by J-Flash (Lite)

Tags: movesense

Trying to upload program to Movesense by JIG
Use “samples\bin\debug\Movesense-movement_wakeup_app_w_bootloader” for example.
There is “sd_bl.bin” and “Movesense.bin”
What prog addr to use for both files?
Where to get more info about it?

If use 0x00000000, then Movesense not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addresses are:
0x00001000 - sd_bl.bin
0x0001f000 - movesense.bin

But not required to set addresses if using
"ninja flash" command to flash the Movesense